# Register resource on the network

Tags: geoserver, wms, esri-geoportal-server

I have installed Geoportal 2.6.5 on Windows.

Now I want add a broker for my GeoServer, but cannot find  URL recourse Register resource on the network.

How I can harvest metadata from GeoServer WMS layer?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/geoportal-server/common-questions ~ suggests you can just 'Copy and paste the resource's Web endpoint, such as various Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) services`